# How to I solve fetch has been blocked by CORS policy when fetch data from contract

Tags: solidity, hardhat, wagmi, sepolia, viem

I'm trying to fetch campaign data and display it to the user. I'm using Nextjs in the front-end and solidity & hardhat in the back-end. The contract data seems to be fetched but when being displayed there is a continuous blick and the loader loads continuously.

###### Error

```
Access to fetch at 'https://rpc.sepolia.org/' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy
```

I have tried installing the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` extension on Brave, but it doesn't work. I have also tried installing `Nextjs Cors` but can't seem to hack it.

[See site behavior](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1erovYOwi5T4jWsAnBXUyNp2IfeBNNS-0/view?usp=drivesdk)
How Can I solve this?

Comment: The site behavior part was due to the wrong implementation of the ```useEffect``` hook. So that's solved. 
The cor error isn't solved yet.

Comment: Did you solve this?